# how to declare an array in xtext

Tags: arrays, eclipse, xtext

I need to declare an integer array in a domain specific language using xtext.

```
PolyLine:
'polyline' color = Color '{'                    Line1
'points number' n = INT                         Line2
'x points'                                      Line3
'y ponts'                                       Line4
'}';
```

In above rule declaration, I need to get several x and y points which indicate some coordination (theirs number is equal to n property in line2). But I can't find any document that help me to answer my question "How I can declare a array in xtext"?
Can somebody help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what your questions targets but you can have lists of things basically using the `+=` operator

`points+=INT+`

`(points+=INT ("," points+=INT)*)`

Comment: I dont understand this question since i dont understand which code you want to generate. f.points is a list of integers.

Comment: I want to generate a method for this rule in java using xtend. Points is a list of integers in my DSL, but I expect, this list transforms to an array in the java class that will be generate later. Is it possible using Terminal rules or I should use xbase and try to handle this problem by choosing JVMTyeReference?

Comment: please give me a sample model and the corresponding output

Comment: i just wanted to know a sample model and a sample java output. it is hard to give advice on how to generate without knowing what to generate

Comment: so what about
`def compile(PolyLine p) '''g.drawPolyline(new int[]{«p.xpoints.join(",")»},new int[]{«p.ypoints.join(",")»},«p.n»);'''`

Comment: Thank you so much Christian.It works and it's exactly what I wanted.