# Array in Xtext without square brackets

Tags: arrays, code-generation, xtext, emf, xtend

I want to implement an array inside a rule in Xtext and use Xtend templates to generate code. I've already checked [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745667/how-to-declare-an-array-in-xtext) but the problem is, that the generator automaticaly adds square brackets to the generated output.

My Xtext rule look like the following example:

```
Rule:
    'Rule' name=ID
    ('myarray' myarray+=DOUBLE(',' myarray+=DOUBLE)*)? &
    'end' 'Rule'
;

terminal DOUBLE returns ecore::EDouble:
    '-'? (("." INT) |
    (INT ("." (INT)?)? (("e" | "E") ("+" | "-")? INT)?))
;
```

When I generate via Xtend, for example with the values `1,2,3` the output is `[1,2,3]` but I want to skip the square brackets and get the output `1,2,3`.

How is it possible?

Comment: You should also show the generator code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use appropriate methods to output the list

e.g.

```
'''«myarray.join(",")»'''
```

or

```
'''«FOR e : myarray SEPARATOR ","»«e»«ENDFOR»'''
```